# Calling a method of a constant object parameter

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants

Here is my code that fails:

```
bool Table::win(const Card &card) {
   for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
      if (card.getRank() == cards[i].getRank()) return true;

   return false;
}
```

Error message is: passing 'const Card' as 'this' argument of 'int Card::getRank()' discards qualifiers.

When I get a copy of the card and change the code to this it works:

```
bool Table::win(const Card &card) {
   Card copyCard = card;

   for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
      if (copyCard.getRank() == cards[i].getRank()) return true;

   return false;
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you please post the `Card`-class declaration?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is `getRank` a const-method? It should be declared like this":

```
int getRank( ) const;
```

Assuming the return type is int.

Comment: So, if I'm passing an object as a constant variable, should I declare all of its methods as constant?

Comment: Read this to understand more about const: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Comment: @pocoa - if a method does not modify an instance, it should be a `const` method.  This allows the method to be called on `const` instances.

Comment: @Samuel: So if I need to call setRank() into that function, I shouldn't pass that object as a const reference right?

Comment: For any parameter, if you need to change it [via a `setRank()` function, for instance], you need to pass it as a non-const reference.

Comment: @BjörnPollex your link is broken

Comment: @JamesWierzba thanks, apparently this has moved to a different location, now link is: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness.

Comment: If only we listened to Tim about [URLs not changing](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) - thanks for updating the link over 5 years later!